# How can I use LOCAL VARIABLE in function, like a GLOBAL VARIABLE variable for other function

Tags: python, selenium, global-variables, sendmail, smtplib

I wrote simple test on selenium, that makes auth on some site, makes parsing of some part of HTML code and sends email to a needed mailbox. I want to make everything beautiful, and I decided to define functions for this code.

My code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import smtplib

CHROME_PATH = '/usr/bin/google-chrome'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
WINDOW_SIZE = "1024,768"

def pgi_auth(sitename, region_pgi, login_pgi, password_pgi):
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
    chrome_options.binary_location = CHROME_PATH
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,chrome_options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(sitename)
    driver.find_element_by_id("LoginId").send_keys(login_pgi)
    driver.find_element_by_id("LoginPassword").send_keys(password_pgi)

    option = Select(
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Region']")
    ).select_by_value(region_pgi)

    driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()

    element = driver.find_element_by_id("TotalCurrentCharges-body").text

    current_charges = element.splitlines()[1]
    print(current_charges)
    driver.quit()

def send_email(host, port, from_addr, password, to_addr, subject, current_charges):
    BODY = "\r\n".join((
        "From: %s" % from_addr,
        "To: %s" % to_addr,
        "Subject: %s" % subject ,
        "",
        body_text
    ))
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(from_addr, password)
    server.sendmail(from_addr, [to_addr], BODY)
    server.quit()

#for pgi_auth
sitename="https://invoiceaccess.pgiconnect.com"
login_pgi="my_secret_login"
password_pgi="my_secret_password"
region_pgi="us"

#for send_email
host = "mail.example.com"
port = "587"
from_addr = "test.mail@example.com"
password = "my_secret_password"
to_addr = "test.receive@example.com"
subject = "MY BALANCE:"

pgi_auth(sitename, region_pgi, login_pgi, password_pgi)
send_email(host, port, from_addr, password, to_addr, subject, current_charges)
```

In my function `pgi_auth`, I am receiving variable `current_charges`
I want to use this variable outside this `pgi_auth` for function `send_email`. Of course, I can make this without functions, but I want to try to make everything beautiful (maybe I will use config), how can I get this variable outside the function?

Comment: make `pgi_auth` return `current_charges` and call it at the end of your code with `current_charges = pgi_auth(sitename...)`. Then pass `current_charges` to `send_email` .

Comment: @Flob sorry ? i tried, to make return, but it says, that
`NameError: name 'current_charges' is not defined`

Comment: that's pretty weird, given that you defined it two lines earlier... i'm sorry, but i don't really know what the caue of this could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `return` keyword in the method

```
def pgi_auth(sitename, region_pgi, login_pgi, password_pgi):
    .....
    .....
    return current_charges

....
....
subject = "MY BALANCE:"

current_charges = pgi_auth(sitename, region_pgi, login_pgi, password_pgi)
send_email(host, port, from_addr, password, to_addr, subject, current_charges)
```

Comment: sorry, but it says, that `NameError: name 'current_charges' is not defined`

Comment: try change variable for `current_charges = pgi_auth(..` and `send_email(..., current_charges)` to something else

Comment: sorry, i did not understand. yes, it works. thank you